# Back/Forward button for tabs - JQuery

Tags: jquery

Okay, so I have a set of tabs, that when clicked change the content in the main content area. That's this code here:

```
var $items = $('.itembox');
$items.click(function() {
    $items.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var index = $items.index($(this));
    $('.currentbox').hide().eq(index).show();


}).eq(0).click();
```

However, I also have a *back*/*forward* button to change between the tabs, but I'm not sure how to implement these buttons as well as having the tabs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why dont u use jQuery UI tabs? they're easy to use and have pretty powerful methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept to get you started. If you're on the last tab and press next it will go to the first tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/AraYd/1/

Some of the important code:

```
   $('#next').click(function(){
     if(index+1 <= $items.length-1) {
        $items[index+1].click(); 
     } else {
       $items[0].click();   
     }
});

   $('#prev').click(function(){
     if(index-1 >= 0) {
   $items[index-1].click(); 
     } else {
     $items[$items.length-1].click();   
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, storing the current (bonus is that clicking the "back" on the first one, takes you to the last one), and you can always query the data from the buttons :)

```
 var $items = $('.itembox');
 $items.click(function () {
     $items.removeClass('current');
     $(this).addClass('current');
     var index = $items.index($(this));
     $('#back').data("currentIndex", index - 1);
     $('#forw').data("currentIndex", index + 1);
     $('.currentBox').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
 }).eq(0).click();
 $('#back, #forw').click(function () {
     $items.eq($(this).data("currentIndex")).click();
 });
```

working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gXpa3/